# How to Fix MFC CStdioFile and CString Garbled Characters while Reading and Dealing with Data in Files?

Tags: c++, file-io, mfc, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Community and MFC

My Code:

```
void CTMCVDlg::FileIO()
{
//  Getting source file path to read and destination file path to write
    CString    destpath, sourcepath, destname;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, sourcepath);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, destpath);
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, destname);
    destpath = GetFilePathExceptFileName(destpath);
    CStdioFile outF(destpath + destname + _T(".osu"), CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
    CStdioFile inF(sourcepath, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeBinary);
//    Operation Log
    AppendText3(_T("Created and opened file \"") + filename + _T(".osu\""));
    AppendText3(_T("Converting..."));
/*
*    I want to read the source file line by line and when I meet a line with 'TimingPoints' the loop stops.
*    szline: read file line by line
*    temp: special string for exception of regular options
*    aa: not used
*/
    CStringW szline = _T("");
    CString temp = _T("");
    CStringA aa = "";
    while (inF.ReadString(szline))
    {
        AppendText3(szline);    // Just debug for what it read
        if (szline.Find(_T("Mode:")) != -1)    // If it meets a line including 'Mode:' then write 'Mode: 3'
        {
            temp = _T("Mode: 3");
            outF.Write(temp, temp.GetLength() << 1);
            outF.Write("\r\n", 2);
        }
        else // else write what it has read.
        {
            outF.Write(szline, szline.GetLength() << 1);
            outF.Write("\r\n", 2);
        }
        if (szline.Find(_T("TimingPoints")) != -1)    // if it meets 'TimingPoints' then exit the loop.
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Input file:
[image]

Output file:
[image]

Debug:
[image]

Text file Encoding: UTF-8

I wonder, why does it all become garbled code while reading into CString objects?

Also, why does the output file have a lot of redundant empty newlines?

Also, I can't let the loop end because it can't find the 'TimingPoints' and the 'Mode:' keywords. I tried to use the `CW2A` macro to convert the wide character into a UTF-8 character, but the output file becomes full of garbled code.

I want to read the input file line by line and search for the keywords to have different operations.

Comment: You're reading UTF-8 text that gets reinterpreted as UTF-16. This is happening here: `inF.ReadString(szline)`. You need to read into a narrow character string if the file uses a narrow character encoding. There are *lots* of other bugs in the code and you should thoroughly read this: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: BTW: don't post pictures of text. Post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: i read that but still have no idea about how can i fix the code and achieve the function... sorry for being a programming noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really read your file line-by-line, because of lack of proper functions:

- `CStdioFile::ReadString()` both expects Unicode content in the file and returns a Unicode string (assuming you are compiling with the Unicode option). Unfortunately there is no overloaded version of `ReadString()` that reads a `CStringA` string.
- `CFile` class doesn't have a function that can read a file line-by-line, the class is basically meant for binary file I/O.

I can think two possible solutions:

- Use the `CFile` class to read a part of the file each time. You will be reading a buffer, and you will have to convert it to wide-string and implement your own buffer management and separation of lines.
- Don't use `CFile`/`CStdioFile`, instead use C++ classes, or even C functions.

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try std::string for another way ;w;